# Displaying titles in test explorer with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, testing, resharper

Is there a way to display titles using visual studio. I am having trouble using test explorer and I looked at video examples of how to do it with the test explorer but mine shows different things than the video

Comment: So you mean categories like here http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2?

Comment: Not completely, I mean when you give your unit tests a certain importance e.g. (at) = @ (at)slow, (at)fast, (at)Important etc it's supposed to allow you to categorize your unit tests based on the tags in test explorer but It won't give me the option to (basing it from videos that I have watched and tried to press the same button yet get different results)